# symfony get values from select box

Tags: symfony

## i want to get the values of a select box from this form

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
            ->add('manifestations', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'PrifProtocoleBundle:Manifestation',
                'multiple' => true,
                'required'=>false
            ));
}
```

## i've tried:

```
$manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData();
```

## and

```
$manifestations = $this->getValue('manifestations');
```

## but no result! does anyone has a detailed solution for a newbie? thanks

Comment: Is '$form['manifestations']->getData();' returns null? Can you show your controller's code?

Comment: i made a var_dump($manifestations); i get some results with $form['manifestations']->getData();' thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData();
```

works fine for me. If in the Manifestation class you have field $name, then you can use `getName()` method. Like this:

```
$manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData();
$name = $manifestations->getName();
```

Or you can use Request:

```
$form = $request->request->get('form');
$manifestations = $form['manifestations'];
```

**P.S.:** '`form`' is the name of your form.

Comment: $manifestations = $form['manifestations']->getData(); works fine actually. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch like this one

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function testAction(Request $request){
     $data=$request->request->all(); $data['form_name']['manifestations'];
    or  $data['manifestations'];
return new response(json_encode($data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ashot's answer working well. 
In my case:

```
$currency = $form['currency']->getData();
var_dump($currency->getName());
```

Output:

```
string(3) "USD"
```